Difference between DSEM and Latent Trajectory with Structured Residuals
I am having a find time understanding the difference between Dynamic Structural Equation Modelling (Asparouhov et al., 2018) and Latent Trajectory with Structured Residuals (Curran et al., 2014). I am building a model to analyse a trajectory of depression over 5 years, and the effects of time-varying predictors (personality, negative events).
https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2013-44751-001
https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10705511.2017.1406803

Hi, and welcome to the Stack! This question isn't quite right for our this site, for a couple of reasons: 1) Stackoverflow is a site for questions that are specifically about programming, and this question is about statistical modelling. 2) This question doesn't have enough focus - SO is designed to give specific answers to specific problems or questions.

If you can formulate a specific question about this topic, you might be able to get an answer on the statistics stack exchange. Otherwise you could try the talk page of that site, but you'll need 20 rep to post there. For more information about how to ask a good question, take the [tour].
